# Unable to find SqlPlus processes running when executing shell script via Crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a shell script that's being executed via Crontab. The shell script is properly creating the Sqlplus jobs and they run to completion. What's not working is the while loop at the end where I want the script to wait for all of the Sqlplus jobs to complete.

If I execute this shell script manually, the while loop at the end works properly and the shell script won't exit until all the Sqlplus jobs have finished.

How do I get the while loop at the end to see the Sqlplus jobs while running via Crontab?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /some/path/to/folder

source ~/.profile

echo 'Run started'
echo $(date)

i=0
while [ $i -lt 12 ]
do
    echo 'Starting process ' $i

    sqlplus username/password@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVERSID)))' @import.sql $i > import_batch$i.log &

    let i=$i+1
done

while [ $(ps -a | grep -w -c 'sqlplus') -ne 0 ] //This is not working in Crontab
until [[ -z $(pgrep -flx 'sqlplus') ]] //I've also tried this (instead of the while in my script) without success in Crontab
do
    sleep 60
done

echo 'Run completed'
echo $(date)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use "wait"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: get rid of the whole while/until loop and replace it with 'wait'.  'wait' waits for all background processes own by the current process to exit.  Try it interactively with something like: sleep 2 & sleep 3 & wait

Comment: @linuts : you're absolutely right. I should have freshened up my memory of UNIX job control before suggesting my dumb answers. You should put your comment as an answer, I think you nailed it and deserve the bounty.

Comment: I updated my script to use wait instead of the loop. I'll know more after it runs early tomorrow morning.

Comment: @linuts : The wait worked! If you want to post that as an answer I'll award you the bounty. Otherwise it'll go to Miklos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment above, use "wait" to wait for all processes owned by this process to comlete.  e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /some/path/to/folder

source ~/.profile

echo 'Run started'
echo $(date)

i=0
while [ $i -lt 12 ]
do
    echo 'Starting process ' $i

    sqlplus username/password@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVERSID)))' @import.sql $i > import_batch$i.log &

    let i=$i+1
done

wait

echo 'Run completed'
echo $(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use `ps -ax` in the crontab case ?

```
while [ $(ps -ax | grep -w -c 'sqlplus') -ne 0 ]
```

**EDIT 2013-04-27** : scratch that, that's dumb. As linuts suggested, just use [`wait`](http://www.gb.nrao.edu/~jford/bash/bashref.html#SEC77).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /some/path/to/folder

source ~/.profile

echo 'Run started'
echo $(date)

i=0
while [ $i -lt 12 ]
do
    echo 'Starting process ' $i

    sqlplus username/password@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVERSID)))' @import.sql $i > import_batch$i.log &

    let i=$i+1
done

wait
echo 'Run completed'
echo $(date)
```

Comment: I updated my script to try the -ax option. It's a very large job and runs once a day, I won't know if it helped until tomorrow.

Comment: It ran last night but the while loop still didn't catch with the -ax option.

Comment: Is this running on a Linux system? You could try using `while [ pidof -s sqlplus ]` or `while [ pgrep sqlplus ]` instead... Be sure to test it manually first.

Comment: Yes it is. I updated the loop to do a `until [[ -z $(pgrep -flx 'sqlplus') ]]`. I'll see how that works over the weekend.

Comment: No luck with the pgrep and pidof isn't available on this machine (I don't have the ability to add it or ask for it to be added)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ps -axww | grep -w 'sqlplus' | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

because `ps -axww | grep -w -c 'sqlplus'` will always include 1 line for `grep -w -c 'sqlplus'` command

Alternatively, try using following to match `sqlplus` pattern exactly or as regex

```
pgrep -fl 'sqlplus'
pgrep -flx '.*sqlplus.*'
```

Comment: The matching is working in the bash script, I think it has more to do with ps and pgrep not finding the running sqlplus jobs when it's being exectued via Crontab

Comment: have you tried saving the output of `ps -ax` in a separate file so you can see what `grep` is matching against?

Comment: No I haven't, I'll do that and see what I get. I have however ran the same script manually and it will wait for the sqlplus jobs to finish.