# open sqlplus connection only once in while loop

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have 100 records. When I am running the code below, the SQL*Plus connection is opening many times utilizing 100% of CPU. Is there any way in which I could open SQL*Plus connection only once, i. e. outside `while` loop?

```
**#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/software/oracle/ora10204
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
INPUT_FILE='file.csv'
IFS=','
i=0
while read name id do
a[i]="$name"
b[i]="$id"
echo "${a[$i]}  ${b[$i]}"
set serveroutput on;
sqlplus .../...@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=...)(HOST=...)(PORT=...)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=...)))'<<EOF
insert into code_entry(inh_valu,edi_valu) values('${a[$i]}' , '${b[$i]}');
EOF
let i=$i+1
done < $INPUT_FILE**
```

Comment: Here's an inline link to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192414/unable-to-find-sqlplus-processes-running-when-executing-shell-script-via-crontab#comment23258650_16253971)

Comment: Is this data file on the server or a separate client? Have you looked at using SQL*Loader or an external table to load this file?

Comment: Similar question: [connect to sqlplus only once without writing to a file in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273838/427158)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SQL script, that you would invoke once in the end of your shell script with SQL*Plus. It would use `INSERT ALL` DML command, and you would just append the strings to it using your shell script and redirect operator (`>>`) within your existing loop.

After running your shell script your SQL script could look like this:

```
insert all
into code_entry (inh_valu, edi_valu) values (1, 'foo')
into code_entry (inh_valu, edi_valu) values (2, 'bar');
...
```

You would then just run it like this:

```
$ sqlplus scott/tiger @myscript.sql
```

A sample shell script could look like:

```
echo "insert all" > myscript.sql

INPUT_FILE='file.csv'
IFS=','
i=0
while read name id do
  a[i]="$name"
  b[i]="$id"
  echo "into code_entry(...) values ('${a[$i]}', '${b[$i]}')" >> myscript.sql
  let i=$i+1
done < $INPUT_FILE**

echo ";" >> myscript.sql

sqlplus .../...@'(DESCRIPTION=...)' @myscript.sql
```

Comment: Or, better use [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/cncptdba.htm#CNCPT1282), it's more suitable for ETL.

Comment: the following errors are coming.... 1.syntax error near unexpected token `done'
2. `done < $INPUT_FILE'

Comment: I outlined the process assuming you've got some basic understanding of writing shell scripts and using SQL*Plus. I cannot write all the code for you. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the above question..ur code is really very helpful..thankyou so much for the help